# listview empty view never shows

Tags: android-listview

I am using SherlockListActivity with ListView.
When there are no items in the list, I would like to display the no_data string.
I have followed several examples using @android:id/empty but they don't work for me.
The 'empty' text view is never visible. Any help is appreciated. 
This is my layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_data"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how my listview is filled in my MainActivity Java file

```
private void fillData()
{     
    // Get cursor of name, bal, date for account list
    Cursor cursor = db.getCursor();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

   // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
   String[] columns = new String[] { "accounts.name", "accounts.bal", "accounts.ot"};

   // THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO
   int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvName,R.id.tvBal, R.id.tvDate };

   // CREATE THE ADAPTER USING THE CURSOR POINTING TO THE DESIRED DATA AS WELL AS THE LAYOUT     INFORMATION
   SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main_list_item, cursor, columns, to);

  // SET THIS ADAPTER AS YOUR LISTACTIVITY'S ADAPTER
  this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

This is how I create the Cursor in a separate Java Class

```
    // Getting All accounts
    public Cursor getCursor() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, new String[] {
                    KEY_AID,     // Account ID Integer
                    KEY_NAME,    // Name of account 
                    KEY_BAL,     // Balance
                    KEY_ADATE,   // Occurrence time 

                    }, 
                    KEY_TYPE + "=?",
                    new String[] {"2"}, null, null, null);

            // return account list
            return cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following in the OnCreate Method of my ListActivity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I found this by going back to the Notepad example and comparing it closely to my project.
Even though I forgot to set the layout.xml, the listview itself still worked. I believe this is because the default ListActivity layout is a single listview with the id of android:id/list. 
Now that the proper layout.xml is being used, the text view with id @android:id/empty is also working.
Apologies because I didn't include the OnCreate method of my MainActivity when I posted the question and that's where the problem was.